# quarkus building dynamic queries

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

in Spring Boot you would probbably do something like this.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Car> cq = cb.createQuery(Car.class);

Root<Car> book = cq.from(Car.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

if (request.carOwner() != null) {
    predicates.add(cb.equal(book.get("carOwner"), request.carOwner()));
}
if (request.states() != null) {
    predicates.add(cb.in(book.get("state")).value(request.states()));
}
cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

TypedQuery<Car> query = em.createQuery(cq);
Page<Car> result = new PageImpl<Car>(query.getResultList(), page, totalRows);

return result;
```

but i cant find any example nor anything how to build queries like this in quarkus..
Could you provide me with documentation pelase?